# Change default start location in hyper.is terminal

Tags: terminal

On OSX, every time I start my hyper.is terminal I have to `cd desktop`, is there a way to configure it to start in /desktop by default instead of the root folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how this would be done in `hyper.is` but this can be done more generally by adding `cd ~/Desktop` to your bash profile. This can be done by running the following:

```
echo "cd ~/Desktop" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me :(

Here's what worked, which is also answered on [How do you change the start location for the hyper.is terminal on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70738129/how-do-you-change-the-start-location-for-the-hyper-is-terminal-on-osx)

"I spent hours on this yesterday! I ended up having to update the .zschrc file.

I made a [walkthrough](https://dev.to/jennjunod/cant-update-terminal-directory-4eo7) to hopefully save other people the time to do this.

Even though this walkthrough doesn't talk about Hyper, it did update Hyper as well. "

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, if you have Git installed:

1. Goto *hamburger icon* -> Edit -> Preferences
2. Add `shell: 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe'` to your *.hyper.js* file.
3. Save and then open .*bash_profile* file and add `cd <whatever location you want>` and save it.
4. Reopen Hyper to see the changes.