# How do you change the start location for the hyper.is terminal on OSX

Tags: terminal, hyper

I don't understand the instructions on the hyper website.

My understanding is that if I edit the `~/.hyper.js` file then I can just update the "shell" field. But I don't know what to update in the field if I want the terminal to start on my desktop rather than the root where it currently starts.

This was the closest answer I could find was me asking the same question a few years ago. [Change default start location in hyper.is terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934110/change-default-start-location-in-hyper-is-terminal) The response seemed to work for me then but something must have changed because running the same command doesn't do anything now.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this yesterday! I ended up having to update the .zschrc file.

I made a [walkthrough](https://dev.to/jennjunod/cant-update-terminal-directory-4eo7) to hopefully save other people the time to do this.

Even though this walkthrough doesn't talk about Hyper, it did update Hyper as well.

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33666173)